POP_OS built-in microphone is unplugged
I have a problem with the built-in mic after an update. It worked normally before. I don't see it in the audio settings, and it is unplugged into the pavucontrol. Do someone have any advice?
OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Kernel: 6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic
Notebook: https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_T14_Gen_4_AMD?M=21K3003RCK
I tried the steps from https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/: restart/reinstall pipwire, remove the configuration,...


systemctl --user status pipewire
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-06-07 14:05:14 CEST; 1h 9min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 15298 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 36835)
     Memory: 10.4M
        CPU: 4.160s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─15298 /usr/bin/pipewire

Jun 07 14:05:14 tp-lukas systemd[3728]: Started PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Jun 07 14:05:14 tp-lukas pipewire[15298]: mod.jackdbus-detect: Failed to receive jackdbus reply: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name is not activatable



systemctl --user status pipewire-pulse
● pipewire-pulse.service - PipeWire PulseAudio
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire-pulse.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-06-07 14:05:14 CEST; 1h 11min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire-pulse.socket
   Main PID: 15301 (pipewire-pulse)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 36835)
     Memory: 27.8M
        CPU: 3.829s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire-pulse.service
             └─15301 /usr/bin/pipewire-pulse

Jun 07 14:05:14 tp-lukas systemd[3728]: Started PipeWire PulseAudio.



systemctl --user status wireplumber
● wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/wireplumber.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-06-07 14:05:14 CEST; 1h 12min ago
   Main PID: 15300 (wireplumber)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 36835)
     Memory: 6.0M
        CPU: 395ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/wireplumber.service
             └─15300 /usr/bin/wireplumber

Jun 07 14:05:14 tp-lukas systemd[3728]: Started Multimedia Service Session Manager.
Jun 07 14:05:14 tp-lukas wireplumber[15300]: SPA handle 'api.libcamera.enum.manager' could not be loaded; is it installed?
Jun 07 14:05:14 tp-lukas wireplumber[15300]: PipeWire's libcamera SPA missing or broken. libcamera not supported.
Jun 07 14:05:15 tp-lukas wireplumber[15300]: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x5d8bd690db80> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
Jun 07 14:05:15 tp-lukas wireplumber[15300]: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x5d8bd690db80> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
Jun 07 14:05:15 tp-lukas wireplumber[15300]: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x5d8bd690db80> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera



lspci -v | grep -A6 Audio
pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted
64:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1640
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 50d9
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 92, IOMMU group 17
    Memory at 785c8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
--
64:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 63)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 91, IOMMU group 21
    Memory at 78580000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at 1c10000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
--
64:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Lenovo Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 93, IOMMU group 22
    Memory at 785c0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+



arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0



pactl list cards
Card #49
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_64_00.1
    Driver: alsa
    Owner Module: n/a
    Properties:
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x785c8000 irq 92"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        api.alsa.path = "hw:0"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:64:00.1"
        device.description = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_64_00.1"
        device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.plugged.usec = "80933960"
        device.product.id = "0x1640"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:64:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        media.class = "Audio/Device"
        factory.id = "14"
        client.id = "38"
        object.id = "49"
        object.serial = "49"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x785c8000 irq 92"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.string = "0"
    Profiles:
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 3, sources: 0, priority: 1, available: yes)
    Active Profile: off
    Ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "0"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround71
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (type: HDMI, priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "1"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (type: HDMI, priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "2"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2

Card #50
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_64_00.6
    Driver: alsa
    Owner Module: n/a
    Properties:
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "1"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x785c0000 irq 93"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        api.alsa.path = "hw:1"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:64:00.6"
        device.description = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_64_00.6"
        device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.plugged.usec = "81012987"
        device.product.id = "0x15e3"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:64:00.6/sound/card1"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        media.class = "Audio/Device"
        factory.id = "14"
        client.id = "38"
        object.id = "50"
        object.serial = "50"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:1"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x785c0000 irq 93"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.string = "1"
    Profiles:
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: no)
        pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "mic"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                card.profile.port = "0"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                port.type = "speaker"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                card.profile.port = "1"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "headphones"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
                card.profile.port = "2"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo



pactl list sources
Source #59
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_64_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_64_00.6.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.id = "ALC257 Analog"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x785c0000 irq 93"
        alsa.name = "ALC257 Analog"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x785c0000 irq 93"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        api.alsa.path = "front:1"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "1"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "3"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "monitor"
        device.id = "50"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.routes = "2"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        device.description = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_64_00.6.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "ALC257 Analog"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:1:front:1:playback"
        priority.driver = "1009"
        priority.session = "1009"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "38"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "merge"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "59"
        object.serial = "59"
        node.max-latency = "16384/44100"
        api.alsa.period-size = "1024"
        api.alsa.period-num = "32"
        api.alsa.headroom = "0"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "1"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:64:00.6"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_64_00.6"
        device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.plugged.usec = "81012987"
        device.product.id = "0x15e3"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:64:00.6/sound/card1"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.string = "1"
    Ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, availability group: Legacy 2, availability unknown)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
    Active Port: analog-output-speaker
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #60
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_64_00.6.analog-stereo
    Description: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.id = "ALC257 Analog"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x785c0000 irq 93"
        alsa.name = "ALC257 Analog"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x785c0000 irq 93"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        api.alsa.path = "front:1"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "1"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "capture"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "0"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.id = "50"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.routes = "1"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.source"
        media.class = "Audio/Source"
        device.description = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        node.name = "alsa_input.pci-0000_64_00.6.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "ALC257 Analog"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:1:front:1:capture"
        priority.driver = "2009"
        priority.session = "2009"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "38"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "split"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "60"
        object.serial = "60"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "1"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:64:00.6"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_64_00.6"
        device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.plugged.usec = "81012987"
        device.product.id = "0x15e3"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:64:00.6/sound/card1"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.string = "1"
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
    Active Port: analog-input-mic
    Formats:
        pcm

